# override ctrl-click links target in vscode editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing jsonschema definitions in various files organized in a dir structure.
schemas may refer each other via `"$ref"`ering to the final target URI, (typically an HTTPS URI)
The `"$ref"` property - e.g. `"https://my-domain.org/.schemas/path/to/the/specific/schema"` - gets highlited as a link that opens the browser when ctrl-clicked
But when developing it would be convenient to open the corresponding file (e.g. `"${WORKSPACE}/src/path/to/the/specific/schema"`)

How can I properly override the target link in vscode editor for that workspace ?

Comment: you can try the extension I made: [HTML Related Links](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.html-related-links), I don't know if it will override the VSC version of doc links

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that VSCode doesn't understand `$id` in schemas.  That means that it treats all URIs as locators and tries to download them.

We (JSON Schema) have opened multiple issues on their lack of support for various JSON Schema features, but it doesn't appear to be something they're interested in fixing.